# Array indices in Python slicing

Tags: python

Can someone please explain how slicing works in following statements?

1. `bbox[:, [0, 2]] = width - bbox[:, [2, 0]]`

*width is the width of a 2D image

What is the role of [0,2] in the above statement?

2. `iw = (torch.min(boxes[:, 2:3], query_boxes[:, 2:3].t()) - torch.max(boxes[:, 0:1], query_boxes[:, 0:1].t()) + 1).clamp(min=0)`

What is the role of 2:3, or 0:1 in the above statement?

Thanks!

Comment: What types are `bbox` and `boxes`?

Comment: Just what part of this confuses you?  We don't want to get into giving a redundant tutorial on Python slicing syntax and semantics.  You appear to be using a data type included in `torch`, which means that the semantics are controlled by that class, and you should find the necessary information in the package documentation.

Comment: @Daniel, I think it will help for you to try and construct a minimum working example of the thing you're confused about. Often I find that I answer my own questions by trying to make a code that communicates what I want for an SO post. So, what's the output of `type(bbox)`? What's an example of an object this code will execute on?

Comment: This is not valid syntax for list slicing, so `bbox` can't be a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bbox` looks like numpy arrays and numpy slicing is a bit different from python lists. Here is the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html) on indexing